# How to use a tangent circle in a numerical method for complex-valued differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, approximation

If you solve the equation

$$\frac{dz}{dt}=-i\omega z$$

with initial value $z(0)=1$ you get

$$z = e^{-i\omega t}$$

which traces a circle in the complex plane with angular speed $-\omega$.  If you try to the Euler method of approximating the solution, it diverges because

$$z_1 = z_0 + h(-i\omega)z_0 = (1-ih\omega)z_0$$

and

$$|z_1| = |1-ih\omega| = \sqrt{1+(h\omega)^2}$$

for $h,\omega >0$.  Likewise $|z_{n+1}|>|z_n|$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I'm trying to think of ways to fix this, so that $|z_{n+1}| \leq |z_n|$ and preferably with equality.  I tried using the second term of the Taylor series so that the approximation didn't merely make a linear approximation, but the same problem persisted.

It occurs to me that a better method might be to approximate this not with a polynomial but with a circle.  I recall from calc 3 the osculating circle, but that was for a curve whose parameterization we already knew, so I'm not sure if I can leverage that.  Another thought is that rather than the scheme

$$y_{n+1}=y_n+hy'_n$$

which moves from $y_n$ linearly by adding a multiple of $h$, I might want to rotate using complex multiplication, something like $z_{n+1}=z_nr_ne^{i\omega_nh}$ where $r_n\in\mathbb{R}$ would be the radius of the rotation, larger for when larger curvature is appropriate, and $\omega_n$ controlling the speed and direction--again, of course, $h$ serving as the step-size.  I probably would need to do something to deal with the issue of locating the center of the rotation.

I know what I've done is not quite right because I'd have to also account for the center of the rotation, but before going down that road I wanted to know if what I'm attempting is even workable.  The big hurdle I can't quite figure out is how I might decide $r_n$ and $\omega_n$ at each stage, using only the derivative information.  If I understand it correctly, $\frac{dz}{dt}$ gives only the linear approximation of the direction of the complex number, like with a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need implicit methods to preserve the radius. For instance the midpoint method will preserve the radius but not the angular speed. The factor there is $\frac{1-ihω/2}{1+ihω/2}$ so that its absolute value is $1$. Also investigate symplectic methods like Verlet, however there the real and imaginary part are treated differently.

Comment: +1 for the symplectic integrators. In this simple case symplectic Euler method can work too.

Comment: @Evgeny : Symplectic Euler does not work exactly as wanted. While the orbits will remain periodic, they follow ellipses, not the circle of the exact solution. With the deviation proportional to the step size.